# Copy a window's titlebar's text?

Tags: windows-10, screenshot, title-bar, irfanview

How can I copy the full text of a Windows program's titlebar, the actual letters not just a screenshot, to then paste into e.g. Notepad?  In this example, I'd like to get the literal text

`screenshot.png - IrfanView (Zoom: 1674 x 1046) (Selection: 811, 212; 2137 x 1312; 1.629)`

Saving the text to a hardcoded filename or someplace else is fine, too.  I just want to avoid manually reading it and typing it, which is slow and error-prone.

[image: example]

Comment: Although it is not what you are asking, you have skills.. I would suggest writing this.  It wouldn't be difficult especially if it is for your own sole purpose using IrfanView. `EnumWindows()`, `GetWindowText()`, write to the windows clipboard, open the notepad, `SetWindowText()` on the text control.. or even open a text file and dump.

Comment: @John answer is better than my suggestion.  I wasn't aware of said already written app.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas In these modern times I'd trust my own C++ more than a closed-source utility.  But it's only been a few minutes so far, let's see what else turns up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to copy a window's titlebar's text to the clipboard. It provides the function [WinGetActiveTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinGetActiveTitle.htm), which may be used as follows:

```
#z::
WinGetActiveTitle, Title
Clipboard := Title
return
```

Comment: https://safeweb.norton.com/report/show?url=autohotkey.com/download is reassuring!

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey

Answer (score 1):

There is not any native way to copy text from the Windows title bar. True in Windows 11 and 10 and as far back as I know.

I suggest you try this third party program (there may be others):

[Copy title bar text](https://www.thefreewindows.com/28310/copy-text-titlebars-elsewere-open-windows-easily-getwindowtext/)

> Copy text from titlebars and elsewere in open windows easily, with
> GetWindowText
>
> This free, portable and light program lets you copy text from places
> where normally you are unable to copy, such as title bars, status
> bars, toolbars, etc.
>
> The program features a crosshair you can drag and put above the
> element you need to copy. As this crosshair floats above open windows
> it is immediately updated showing text that can be copied. Releasing
> the crosshair stops this procedure and you are able to copy any text
> current displayed on the program’s panel.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following [voice command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38514457/395857) by [PGilm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5521857/pgilm) in Dragon Professional Individual to copy a window's titlebar's text to the clipboard:

```
'
'   get window title
'
Sub Main
    Clipboard ( GetWindowTitle )
End Sub
'
'   Use these Windows Functions for Getting an active Window title
'
Declare Function GetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
'
Declare Function GetWindowText Lib "user32" _
    Alias "GetWindowTextA" ( ByVal hwnd As Long , _
        ByVal lpString As String , ByVal cch As Long ) As Long
'
'   GetWindowTitle
'   (Gets an active Window title)
'
Function GetWindowTitle() As String
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim TitleText As String * 300
    Dim hw As Long
    hw = GetForegroundWindow()
    x = GetWindowText ( hw , TitleText , Len ( TitleText ) )
    GetWindowTitle = Trim ( Left ( TitleText , x ) )
End Function
'
```

[image]

Tested with Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 professional on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate and Dragon Professional Individual 15.6 on Windows 10 Pro.